# Group By clause returning too many rows

Tags: sql, group-by, null

I have a table I'm trying to sort by column values in Stage.

It looks something like this:

| CaseID | Stage | EventDate |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | A | 01/01/10 |
| 1 | B | 01/03/10 |
| 1 | B | 01/04/10 |
| 1 | C | 01/05/10 |
| 2 | A | 02/01/10 |
| 2 | B | 02/02/10 |
| 2 | C | 02/03/10 |
| 2 | C | 02/05/10 |

I'm trying to organize the data by the Stage so that only the latest `EventDate` is shown - something like this:

| CaseID | A | B | C |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 01/01/10 | 01/04/10 | 01/05/10 |
| 2 | 02/01/10 | 02/02/10 | 02/05/10 |

I did a `group by` statement

```
SELECT 
    CaseID,
    CASE WHEN Stage = 'A' THEN MAX(EventDate) END AS A,
    CASE WHEN Stage = 'B' THEN MAX(EventDate) END AS B,
    CASE WHEN Stage = 'C' THEN MAX(EventDate) END AS C
FROM
    StageTable
GROUP BY 
    CaseID, Stage
```

But this returned too many rows with NULL placeholders:

| CaseID | A | B | C |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 01/01/10 | NULL | NULL |
| 1 | NULL | 01/04/10 | NULL |
| 1 | NULL | NULL | 01/05/10 |
| 2 | 02/01/10 | NULL | NULL |
| 2 | NULL | 02/02/10 | NULL |
| 2 | NULL | NULL | 02/05/10 |

I'd like for each row to condense, but I don't know where I went wrong. I've seen other questions with similar questions, but they all seemed to have issues with joint tables showing duplicate results.

Any suggestions would be helpful

Comment: Please always tag your SQL requests with your DBMS, so we know what DBMS we shall seek a solution for. (In this case the solution is standard SQL working in about every DBMS, so I could write my answer without knowing your DBMS, but often it is necessary to know the DBMS in order to write an answer.)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You want one result row per CaseID, so `GROUP BY CaseID` only. Then use conditional aggregation, i.e. put the conditions inside `MAX()`.

```
SELECT
  CaseID
  ,MAX(CASE WHEN Stage = 'A' THEN EventDate END) AS A
  ,MAX(CASE WHEN Stage = 'B' THEN EventDate END) AS B
  ,MAX(CASE WHEN Stage = 'C' THEN EventDate END) AS C
FROM StageTable
GROUP BY CaseID
ORDER BY CaseID;
```